# Rails daylight savings issue while searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am searching records in user model. The search attributes  from_date, to_date will be used to searched records in user model based on created_at column.

```
User model : (id, name, created_at)
```

I have the following records in the database.

```
id, name, created_at
 1   jd1    2013-09-04 18:01:57
 2   jd2    2013-09-05 19:01:57
 3   jd3    2013-09-05 23:01:57
```

When i am searching, between "2013-09-04".to_date(from_date) and "2013-09-05".to_date(to_date), only the first two records are being returned. The last one is not being returned. When i change the to_date to "2013-09-06" the last record is showing. This is the query i used.

```
date_range = from_date ... to_date + 1.day
scope :by_date, ->(date_range) {where(created_at: date_range)}

User.by_date(date_range)
```

What is wrong with the query? I think there is daylight time zone issue with it.

Comment: You need to CAST the created_at column as a Date, it is actually a DateTime ;)

Comment: What is the actual SQL being produced?  My guess is you're running into timezone conversions between Rails and your database.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom It produces the following sql : SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`created_at` >= '2013-09-04' AND `users`.`created_at` < '2013-09-06')

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Sorry for the confusion, i updated the question. They are of Date class

Comment: @PeterAlfvin : I updated the sql after yoshiji pointed out.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom Does the accepted answer make sense to you? This seems like it's gotta be either a daylight savings time or time zone issue, in which case I don't see how the cast resolves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your created_at fields as Date:

```
CAST(users.created_at AS DATE)
```

In the where clause:

```
where("CAST(users.created_at AS DATE) BETWEEN ? AND ?", date1, date2 )
```

In your case, with your scope:

```
scope :by_date, lambda{ |date_range| where("CAST(users.created_at AS DATE) BETWEEN ? AND ?", date_range.min, date_range.max ) }
```

Hope this helps!

---

**Bonus:** The short version of CAST, works with PostGre SQL:

```
scope :by_date, lambda{ |date_range| where("users.created_at::date BETWEEN ? AND ?", date_range.min, date_range.max ) }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm having a bad day, but I don't understand why the original SQL (which has < '...-06') doesn't work unless this is really a timezone issue and the dates in question are showing local time but are really "next day" in UTC and are somehow getting turned into the "day before" with the casting. The original SQL certainly works in my environment.